# Remove elements from deep nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I have a list like this. How do I traverse the sublists to remove all the 1.'s but leaving the structure intact? I have attempted with `Drop[list, {1}]` but this removes the first sublist, and the 1.'s are in deeper sublists.

```
{{{1., 1812.}, {1., 4262.}, {1., 1272.}, {1., 4048.}, {1., 
   3961.}, {1., 7739.}, {1., 3173.}, {1., 1201.}, {1., 6856.}, {1., 
   11860.}, {1., 1324.}, {1., 3457.}, {1., 5038.}, {1., 18731.}, {1., 
   4624.}, {1., 6527.}, {1., 4971.}, {1., 4936.}, {1., 2371.}, {1., 
   3750.}, {1., 5660.}, {1., 2451.}, {1., 6293.}, {1., 4577.}, {1., 
   2005.}, {1., 1428.}, {1., 6300.}, {1., 1145.}, {1., 2797.}, {1., 
   3096.}, {1., 3249.}, {1., 2323.}, {1., 4063.}, {1., 3751.}, {1., 
   4430.}, {1., 2228.}, {1., 2141.}, {1., 881.87}, {1., 6139.}, {1., 
   5055.}, {1., 1821.}, {1., 64625.}, {1., 6462.}, {1., 3415.}, {1., 
   5792.}, {1., 2384.}, {1., 2193.}, {1., 2934.}, {1., 5664.}, {1., 
   10404.}, {1., 3382.}, {1., 3105.}, {1., 7323.}, {1., 9947.}, {1., 
   6282.}, {1., 7470.}, {1., 18522.}, {1., 3243.}, {1., 2813.}, {1., 
   5574.}, {1., 2719.}, {1., 7508.}, {1., 3832.}, {1., 5858.}, {1., 
   4174.}, {1., 10320.}, {1., 3402.}, {1., 10592.}}, 
{{1., 1154.}, {1., 2259.}, {1., 650.77}, {1., 1210.}, {1., 1812.}, {1., 
   2630.}, {1., 1373.}, {1., 1028.}, {1., 2351.}, {1., 2614.}, {1., 
   1494.}, {1., 1480.}, {1., 1903.}, {1., 2058.}, {1., 2520.}, {1., 
   3663.}, {1., 2352.}, {1., 1950.}, {1., 1125.}, {1., 1991.}, {1., 
   2718.}, {1., 1447.}, {1., 3137.}, {1., 2014.}, {1., 1040.}, {1., 
   735.41}, {1., 3531.}, {1., 597.25}, {1., 1181.}, {1., 2203.}, {1., 
   1837.}, {1., 1217.}, {1., 1793.}, {1., 2520.}, {1., 1972.}, {1., 
   1021.}, {1., 1317.}, {1., 428.54}, {1., 3340.}, {1., 2294.}, {1., 
   1125.}, {1., 2758.}, {1., 2510.}, {1., 1500.}, {1., 2800.}, {1., 
   1284.}, {1., 1854.}, {1., 1567.}, {1., 3042.}, {1., 3823.}, {1., 
   1852.}, {1., 1550.}, {1., 4062.}, {1., 5808.}, {1., 2971.}, {1., 
   3837.}, {1., 6249.}, {1., 3008.}, {1., 1604.}, {1., 2172.}, {1., 
   1424.}, {1., 2998.}, {1., 3669.}, {1., 2870.}, {1., 2313.}, {1., 
   5777.}, {1., 1945.}, {1., 6480.}}}
```

EDIT: I'm looking for an operation that targets the position of the 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
list[[All, All, 2;;]] (* or *)
Drop[list, None, None, 1]
```

> {{{1812.}, {4262.}, {1272.}, {4048.}, {3961.}, {7739.}, {3173.}, 
>   {1201.}, {6856.}, {11860.}, {1324.}, {3457.}, {5038.}, {18731.},
>   {4624.}, {6527.}, {4971.}, {4936.}, {2371.}, {3750.}, {5660.}, 
>   {2451.}, {6293.}, {4577.}, {2005.}, {1428.}, {6300.}, {1145.}, 
>   {2797.}, {3096.}, {3249.}, {2323.}, {4063.}, {3751.}, {4430.}, 
>   {2228.}, {2141.}, {881.87}, {6139.}, {5055.}, {1821.}, {64625.}, 
>   {6462.}, {3415.}, {5792.}, {2384.}, {2193.}, {2934.}, {5664.}, 
>   {10404.}, {3382.}, {3105.}, {7323.}, {9947.}, {6282.}, {7470.}, 
>   {18522.}, {3243.}, {2813.}, {5574.}, {2719.}, {7508.}, {3832.}, 
>   {5858.}, {4174.}, {10320.}, {3402.}, {10592.}}, {{1154.}, {2259.}, 
>   {650.77}, {1210.}, {1812.}, {2630.}, {1373.}, {1028.}, {2351.}, 
>   {2614.}, {1494.}, {1480.}, {1903.}, {2058.}, {2520.}, {3663.}, 
>   {2352.}, {1950.}, {1125.}, {1991.}, {2718.}, {1447.}, {3137.}, 
>   {2014.}, {1040.}, {735.41}, {3531.}, {597.25}, {1181.}, {2203.}, 
>   {1837.}, {1217.}, {1793.}, {2520.}, {1972.}, {1021.}, {1317.}, 
>   {428.54}, {3340.}, {2294.}, {1125.}, {2758.}, {2510.}, {1500.}, 
>   {2800.}, {1284.}, {1854.}, {1567.}, {3042.}, {3823.}, {1852.}, 
>   {1550.}, {4062.}, {5808.}, {2971.}, {3837.}, {6249.}, {3008.}, 
>   {1604.}, {2172.}, {1424.}, {2998.}, {3669.}, {2870.}, {2313.}, 
>   {5777.}, {1945.}, {6480.}}}

```
{Dimensions @ %, Dimensions[list]}
```

> {{2, 68, 1}, {2, 68, 2}}

```
SeedRandom[1]
lst = RandomReal[100, {100, 1000, 9}];

(res0 = lst[[All,All,2;;]])//RepeatedTiming// First
```

> 0.0022

```
(res1 = Drop[lst, None, None, 1];) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0034

```
(res2 = Map[Rest, lst, {2}];) // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.023

```
(res3 = Replace[lst, ({x_, y__} :> {y}), {2}];) //  RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.139

```
res0 = res1 == res2 == res3
```

> True

Answer (score 6):

If you want to target lists like `{1., 1812.}`, and the level at which they occur can vary, I would use [`Replace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace) with a negative level:

```
Replace[list, {_, b__} :> {b}, {-2}]
```

> {{{1812.}, {4262.}, {1272.}, {4048.}, {3961.}, {7739.}, {3173.}, {1201.}, 
>   {6856.}, {11860.}, {1324.}, {3457.}, {5038.}, {18731.}, {4624.}, {6527.}, 
>   {4971.}, {4936.}, {2371.}, {3750.}, {5660.}, {2451.}, {6293.}, {4577.}, 
>   {2005.}, {1428.}, {6300.}, {1145.}, {2797.}, {3096.}, {3249.}, {2323.}, 
>   {4063.}, {3751.}, {4430.}, {2228.}, {2141.}, {881.87}, {6139.}, {5055.}, 
>   {1821.}, {64625.}, {6462.}, {3415.}, {5792.}, {2384.}, {2193.}, {2934.}, 
>   {5664.}, {10404.}, {3382.}, {3105.}, {7323.}, {9947.}, {6282.}, {7470.}, 
>   {18522.}, {3243.}, {2813.}, {5574.}, {2719.}, {7508.}, {3832.}, {5858.}, 
>   {4174.}, {10320.}, {3402.}, {10592.}}, {{1154.}, {2259.}, {650.77}, {1210.}, 
>   {1812.}, {2630.}, {1373.}, {1028.}, {2351.}, {2614.}, {1494.}, {1480.}, 
>   {1903.}, {2058.}, {2520.}, {3663.}, {2352.}, {1950.}, {1125.}, {1991.}, 
>   {2718.}, {1447.}, {3137.}, {2014.}, {1040.}, {735.41}, {3531.}, {597.25}, 
>   {1181.}, {2203.}, {1837.}, {1217.}, {1793.}, {2520.}, {1972.}, {1021.}, 
>   {1317.}, {428.54}, {3340.}, {2294.}, {1125.}, {2758.}, {2510.}, {1500.}, 
>   {2800.}, {1284.}, {1854.}, {1567.}, {3042.}, {3823.}, {1852.}, {1550.}, 
>   {4062.}, {5808.}, {2971.}, {3837.}, {6249.}, {3008.}, {1604.}, {2172.}, 
>   {1424.}, {2998.}, {3669.}, {2870.}, {2313.}, {5777.}, {1945.}, {6480.}}}

Answer (score 5):

## To remove the 1's specifically:

Something like this uses [ReplaceAll](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to replace all the `1.`'s with the [Nothing](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html) element:

```
lis = (*your data*)
lis /. (1. -> Nothing)
```

## To remove the first element of each sublist at the 2nd level:

In case you case you aren't necessarily using 1.'s, but want to replace just replace the first part of each deeply nested sublist, consider something like [Replace](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html) with a level spec:

```
lis = (*your data*)
Replace[lis, ({x_, y__} :> {y}), {2}]
```

Alternatively:

```
lis = (*your data*)
Map[Rest, lis, {2}]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping for something that doesn't target the number 1. but rather that position.

Comment: @briennakh I'd mention that in the post, but edited.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful.